# Probability task with basketball shoots

Tags: probability

I have a probability task which sounds like this:
*Two basketball players have probability of making points from free throw 0.61 and 0.58 respectively. What is probability that they will score the same result in 3 attempts?*

How I tried to solve this so far:
They can score 3 out of 3, 2 out of 3 (3 ways to do it), 1 out of 3 (3 ways as well), or nothing. So my arithmetic:

$0.61^3 * 0.58^3 +
0.61^2 * 0.39 * 0.58^2 * 0.42 * 3 + 0.61 * 0.39^2 * 0.42^2 * 0.58 * 3 + 0.39^3 * 0.42^3 = 0.13867$

But as far as I know this is not the correct answer and (logically thinking) it seems that this probability should be higher.

Comment: Aren't there 9 ways for the two players to score two baskets out of three? snnsnn, nsnsnn, nnssnn, ...nnsnns?

Comment: Oh yeah, probabably that was my mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(3\cap 3)+P(2\cap 2)+P(1\cap 1)+P(0\cap 0)=(0.61)^3 \cdot  (0.58^3) +
\binom 3 2 \cdot (0.61)^2 \cdot (0.39) \cdot  \binom 3 2\cdot (0.58)^2 \cdot  (0.42) + \binom 3 1 \cdot (0.61)\cdot (0.39)^2\cdot\binom 3 1 \cdot(0.58) \cdot (0.42)^2 + (0.39)^3 \cdot (0.42)^3$